# Software to obfuscate asp.net core application on linux?

Tags: linux, c#, asp.net, obfuscation

I have some problems to find some software to obfuscate my asp.net core application on Linux.

I tried Obfuscar but the problem is he breaks many things in Asp.net core application. And Dotfuscar can't work on Linux just windows.

So my question, is there any commercial or maybe open-source software that can obfuscate my Asp.net core application without any problems on linux?

Comment: isn't it compiled? Can't you just release he executable?

Comment: @Mawg no i can't i need to obfuscate it before release.

Comment: [How can I obfuscate my c# code, so it can't be deobfuscated so easily?]9https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163701/how-can-i-obfuscate-my-c-sharp-code-so-it-cant-be-deobfuscated-so-easily) on Stack Overflow got some good answers and upvotes; there are also may results when Googling. https://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net seems to be recommended. If any of those work, please let us know, in order to help others in future